# Cross product and dot product

Tags: inner-products, products, cross-product

What's the easiest way to understand and prove that $A \cdot B \times C = C \cdot A \times B $ ?

Comment: Just compute $A \cdot (B \times C)$ and $C \cdot (A \times B)$ for arbitrary $A,B,C \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$ (I assume you work in three dimensional real space, otherwise what do you mean by dot and cross products?) and find out that they are equal. I don't see that there is much more to it than that.

Comment: @Nils: well. An identity involving only cross and dot products is invariant under orientation-preserving rotations, so one might hope that such a thing has a geometric interpretation that might afford a conceptually simpler proof.

Comment: @NilsMatthes: although the proof is not neccesarily much simpler, the geometrical intution Qiaochu Yuan mentions is what drives the determinant-based proofs below. Of course, if one knows about wedge products, the whole thing boils down to their associativity...

Comment: @Qiaochu: Still the easiest way to prove the above equality (for my money) is just calculating it. But I realize that my comment answers only half of the question (namely the "proof"-part) and my last sentence is false from the conceptual point of view, which you kindly pointed out. Understanding an equality is as important as seeing why it is true, something I apparently didn't have in mind while typing my comment above.;)

Comment: Thank you. Yes I am working in the three dimensional real space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might make use of the fact that for $A,B,C \in \mathbb R^3$, $A \cdot (B \times C) = (A \times B) \cdot C = \det M$, where $M$ is the matrix made from the column vectors $A, B, C$. Both identities follows from the Sarrus formula for determinants of $3\times 3$ matrices.

Answer (score 2):

Show that the first is the determinant of the matrix whose rows are $A,B,C$.

Answer (score 0):

For $A = (a_1, a_2, a_3)$, $B = (b_1, b_2, b_3$, an $C= (c_1, c_2, c_3)$ you *could* simply just compute each side manually, so you would for example get for the left hand side:

$$\begin{align}
A\cdot B\times C &= (a_1, a_2, a_3)\cdot (b_2c_3 - b_3c_2, b_3c_1 - b_1c_3, b_1c_2 - b_2c_1) \\ &= ...
\end{align}
$$

And then you compute the right hand side and check that you got the same thing.

Q: Is this the easiest way?
A: Probably not, but it might be a good exercise in keeping track of terms.

Added: As for the understanding. The quantity $A\cdot B\times C$ is called a [triple product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product). If the three vectors are not in the same plane, then they span a parallelepiped, and the absolute value of the triple product gives the volume of the the parallelepiped.

Comment: The question asked for a way to "understand and prove" the claim. This might be the easiest way to prove it, but I don't think it contributes much to the understanding of it.

Comment: @MarkDominus: I added a bit more to my answer. Better?

Comment: Thank you. Yes it is better.